# Fixing Compressing Issue During Mastering

Tags: mixing, mastering, compression

I have a mix for mastering with the issue, you can hear in the attached file. The dynamics in the mix, were over- or wrongly compressed so the result is - that dynamics has frequent fluctuations, as shown on the screenshot. Are there any ideas, how to fix that or make it less audibly noticeable? (Request for remix isn't an option.)

[Audio File](https://we.tl/t-xP8aeO4Ojs)

[image: fluctuations]

Comment: I think that's what I'd call well & truly murdered. It's dead & buried, there's no way to dig that back up from the grave. You did keep your still-breathing mix file, pre-master, didn't you?

Comment: How did you get the screen shot?

Comment: This puzzles me most… *"Request for remix isn't an option."* Why? If someone did that for money you want your money back. I wouldn't even give them a second chance, they're obviously incompetent. Please tell me you still have at least the multi-track or project to work from.